# ORA-01008: not all variables bound error and can't identify an unbound variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code and I am being faced with an error as follows:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-06512: at "BOB.ESTIMATE_BOB", line 69
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I've been through all of the variables, and all of them do seem to have a value assigned so I'm scratching my head a little. Can anyone see what else may be causing this please?

```
create or replace procedure ESTIMATE_BOB is

--variables

l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'db1';
file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_ts_name varchar2(30);
v_link_name varchar2(10);
v_csv_name varchar2(100);
EST_ONE_ROW_MB NUMBER ;
TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
SPACE_REQUIRED NUMBER;
TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB NUMBER;
v_Mv_name varchar2(100);
v_sql1 varchar2(1500);
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
owner varchar2(100);
table_name varchar2(100);
driver_table varchar2(100);
mandatory_join varchar2(100);
C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
v_total_driver_only varchar2(100);
--

begin


SELECT tablename into v_csv_name
FROM BOB.BOB_new_table_tracker
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from BOB.BOB_new_table_tracker);

SELECT mv_name into v_Mv_name
FROM BOB.BOB_new_table_tracker_mv
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from BOB.BOB_new_table_tracker_mv);

select link_name into v_link_name from link_and_mail where mdate = (select max(mdate) from link_and_mail);
select distinct targetschema into v_ts_name from BOB.MV_BOB_TABLE;

v_sql1 := 'SELECT /*+ monitor parallel (4)*/ a.owner,
                        a.table_name,
                        b.driver_table,
                        b.mandatory_join,
                        sum(c.sum_bytes) AS "TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB",
                        (sum(c.sum_bytes)) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "EST_ONE_ROW_MB",
                        ((sum(c.sum_bytes)) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT)) * (:TOTAL_ROW_COUNT)AS "SPACE_REQUIRED"
                 FROM dba_tables@db1 a, MV_BOB_TABLE b, '|| v_Mv_name ||' c
                 WHERE a.table_name IN ( SELECT table_name
                                       FROM MV_BOB_TABLE
                                       WHERE driver_table IS NOT NULL
                                             AND   additional_joins IS NULL
                                     )
                 AND   a.owner IN ( SELECT DISTINCT productionschema FROM MV_BOB_TABLE c  )
                 and a.table_name = b.table_name
                 and a.table_name = c.segment_name
                 group by a.owner,a.table_name,b.driver_table,b.mandatory_join
               ORDER BY table_name';

file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV', v_csv_name||'_EST_PROC.csv', 'w', 32767);

--
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'The below report shows total row counts in PROD');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' for unjoined tables in the BOB document:');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,MANDATORY_JOIN,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,SPACE_REQUIRED');
--main loop
open cur for v_sql1 using TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
   loop
      fetch cur into OWNER,TABLE_NAME,MANDATORY_JOIN,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,SPACE_REQUIRED;--,EST_ONE_ROW_MB;
      exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
      execute immediate' select /*+parallel (4)*/ count(*) from '||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink||' b '||','||
driver_table || '@' || l_dblink||' a ' ||' where ' ||mandatory_join into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink into C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      OWNER || ',' ||
                      TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                      TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB || ',' ||
                      EST_ONE_ROW_MB || ',' ||
                      TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' ||
                      C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' || /* This is actually FULL_TABLE_COUNT*/
                      round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7)|| ',' ||
                      round(round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0),0)--SPACE_REQUIRED
                      );


v_total_driver_only := v_total_driver_only + round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0);

end loop;

UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                     'Total Estimated Space Required '|| round(v_total_driver_only,0) ||' MB'
                     );

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);

end ESTIMATE_BOB;
```

I'm just typing these words because the website is telling me it can't post my question because there is not enough words that are not code. I hope this prevents that issue.

Comment: Have you tried initializing the variables `TOTAL_ROW_COUNT, C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT` with any value?

Comment: Thanks - you mean like this TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER := 1; etc? Just tried it, same error reported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA):

> If the dynamic SQL statement does not represent an anonymous PL/SQL block or a CALL statement, repetition of placeholder names is insignificant. Placeholders are associated with bind arguments in the USING clause by position, not by name.

Which means, in this case, the parameter binding is made by position, not by name.
So you need to provide as many parameters in the USING clause as there are parameters strings in the SQL query, and in the same order.

```
open cur for v_sql1 using C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT, C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT, TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
```

Also, make sure all the parameters have value.